# Fire an event when the innerHTML of a <div> changes. In YUI or otherwise

Tags: javascript, dom-events, yui

Is it possible to fire an event when the `innerHTML` of a `<div>` changes?

I am using YUI 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box onchange event for divs. If you want this you are going to have write this yourself (with a timer and storing whats the current value etc).

I would however try to take it a step back and call a method when you change the innerValue of that div to take care of ... w/e.

Comment: I don't have control over the code which changes the innerHTML. That's why I want fire the event.

Answer (score 1):

Use a setter:

```
myDiv.__defineSetter__("innerHTML",
  function(newHTML) {
    ...
  }
);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_Getters_and_Setters

Comment: I found two problems with this approach.

1) The function get's called, but I am not able to actually set the innerHTML now. if I call this.innerHTML = newHTML, then the method get's called infinitely.
2) Doesn't seem to work in Safari and Chrome

Answer (score 1):

I think Fabian's right in that you'll need to user a timer and compare the value.

That being said, the right way to do this in YUI3 would be to define a [synthetic DOM event](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/event/#define) using [later](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/YUI.html#method_later).